# how to "Paginate" results into rows not pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

This one is very difficult for me to word, which is what is failing me in my google searching, i brand new to asp.net and it's giving me some difficulties with the logic of this requirement

I have a bunch of results which are displayed primarily as images with some text overlayed.

I have some HTML that is required to show these images, but it uses custom styling to show each "row" of images, it uses div's for a custom look.

What i'm needing to do, is work out a way in the cshtml file display a html block to start a row, and then output the html for 6 of the items, then close off that row and begin another one and rinse repeat until completed, but i cannot for the life of me work out how i would go about that in asp.net.

This might be a very very simple issue, but due to my inability to word this correctly for google, I'm really struggling to find anything online.

The closest visual example i can think of is something like Netflix, but without the ability to scroll the movies, so all the movies are listed in those rows.

i'm currently using the following method,

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  html...
}
```

My original thought was to have a counter and do a conditional statement when the count hit's six, closing the row and starting a new one, but i cannot work out how to mix that much html into code blocks.

```
@{
 int count = 0;
 foreach(var item in model)
 {
    count++;
    //Output current item's html 
    if(count == 6)
    {
        //End current row, start new row
        count = 0;
    } 
 }
```

but as i mentioned, i can only find how to mix single html elements in with code blocks using the @: method, and i need a block of html.

Adding my controller code as requested, I have it kinda working using viewbag, but the groupedModel seems to split each movie into a separate row.

```
// GET: Movies
public ActionResult Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
{
    var GenreList = new List<string>();

    var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
                   orderby d.Genre
                   select d.Genre;

    GenreList.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreList);

    var movies = from m in db.Movies
                 select m;

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
    }

    var groupedModel = movies.AsEnumerable().Select((e, i) => new { Element = e, Index = i }).GroupBy(e => e.Index % 6).Select(g => g.Select(e => e.Element));
    ViewBag.grouped = groupedModel;

    return View(movies);
}
```

and my view (With most of the HTML removed for ease of reading):

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Genre: @Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All")
            Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        </p>
    }
</p>

@foreach(var group in ViewBag.grouped)
{ 
   <div class="MovieRow">
       @foreach (var item in group)
       { 
           <div class="bob-title">@Html.Display((item as MvcMovie.Models.Movie).Title)</div>
       }
   </div>
}
```

EDIT:

The only problem i have left now, is that i can't seem to get the item variables to output, none of the `@Html.Display((item as MvcMovie.Models.Movie)` sections output anything.

Comment: instead of doing a `foreach` inside a `@{}` you should use `@foreach {` then inside you can put `@{ }` for code blocks and plain HTML for elements you want to create.

Comment: How would i escape the "if(count == 6) {" in order to output html?

Comment: instead of putting `if` inside the `@{ }` you do `@if () {`

Comment: oh, yes sorry that was a very dumb question

Comment: btw, intead of using `ViewBag`, you can pass it to the `View` method: `return View(groupedModel);` and than use `Model` in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's group your model to get groups with 6 elements (better to do it in the controller, not in the view):

```
var groupedModel = Model.Select((e, i) => new { Element = e, Index = i })
                        .GroupBy(e => (e.Index - 1) / 6)
                        .Select(g => g.Select(e => e.Element));
```

than you will iterate these group and display them:

```
@foreach(var group in groupedModel)
{
    <div id="rowDiv">
    @foreach(var element in group)
    {
        <div id="elementDiv">// element div here
            // display element info here
        </div>// element div end
    }
    </div>    // row div end
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, i never even thought about doing in the controller (and that is pretty stupid of me as a mvvm developer!) I'll give this a try.

Comment: I think this answer needs a little bit more work, `foreach` should be `@foreach`. The `Select` needs to be formatted better

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll have to get back to you on this, as i clearly don't understand how controllers work as well as i had hoped, as i cannot work out how to use your controller code and pass it to the view as an action result.

Comment: This has a problem of reordering things potentially. The groups will be "1,7,13", "2,8,14", etc. To keep the groups as 1-6, 7-12, etc. you can use integer division - `(e.Index-1)/6` will be 0 for 1-6, 1 for 7-12, etc.

Comment: Thanks chris, that solved that little issue perfectly :)